# Ejecutar Script al iniciar Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, servidor

Yo quiero que al iniciar Ubuntu 16.04 , este de manera automática me ejecute un script, hasta el momento tengo lo siguiente:

**script.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir prueba_carpeta
```

y lo que eh hecho para que se ejecute de manera automática es lo siguiente:

- Le doy permisos.

  ```
  sudo chmod +x script.sh
  ```
- Lo agrego en el rc.local

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/rc.local
  ```

**rc.local**

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
sh /var/www/html/script.sh
exit 0
```

Pero no funciona, también probé:

```
sudo mv /var/www/html/script.sh /etc/init.d/
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/script.sh 
sudo update-rc.d script.sh defaults
```

Pero tampoco funciono, Aclaro que después de realizar cada forma, reinicio el S.O. , También aclaro que cuando ejecuto el script en consola, si funciona.

Comment: Te puede servir este post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188042/running-a-script-during-booting-startup-init-d-vs-cron-reboot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con respeto, la respuesta de César es válida pero no la más eficiente. Si quieres ejecutar el script durante el inicio del sistema, tienes que agregar un enlace simbólico en el directorio `/etc/rc.d/`:

Comando para crear el enlace simbólico en tu caso:

```
ln -s /var/www/html/script.sh /etc/rc.d/.
```

También puede solventar tu problema poner la ruta absoluta del programa, es decir, utilizar en tu script `mkdir /var/www/html/prueba_carpeta` en vez de `mkdir prueba_carpeta`.

Ten en cuenta que este sistema es más eficiente (en la mayoría de los casos), pero en las últimas versiones de algunos SO (las últimas versiones de Debian por ejemplo), tienes que incluir las opciones `start`, `stop`, `restart`, `force-reload`, y `status` en tu script.

En caso de que te salga que no existe el directorio ´/etc/rc.d´ ejecuta `runlevel`, esto da como resultado un número (del 1 al 6), teniendo en cuenta el número ejecuta el comando `ln -s /var/www/html/script.sh /etc/rc?.d/.` cambiando el `?` por el número que te ha salido antes (al ejecutar `runlevel`)

Comment: Hola @hamza , estaba probando tu respuesta pero me marca el siguiente error: ln: target '/etc/rc.d/' is not a directory: No such file or directory

Comment: Ejecuta `runlevel` , fijate en el número que te indica y utilizas `ln -s /var/www/html/script.sh /etc/rc?.d/.`  (cambia el ? por el número que te ha salido antes)

Comment: Funciono Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar un [Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job para que se ejecuta al reiniciar. Es probable que la implementación de tu sistema operativo soporte el macros `@reboot` (es lo más probable, yo tuve algunos problemas con otras distribuciones de Linux). Lo que tienes que hacer es editar el `crontab` de tu usuario:

```
$ crontab -e
```

Y agregar la ruta de tu script usando `@reboot`:

```
@reboot /var/www/html/script.sh
```

Es lo más sencillo, yo lo uso todo el tiempo.

Comment: Funciono Gracias.